# Loop through table adding values to another

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Having one table with seven scored items (valued 1 to 6) and another for summarizing this values (counting how many differents scores has each item), I connect them but I'm unable to write the right loop. My code just adds +1 to each cell for every loop (7 times).

Scores table is called "alumne" and values are at column 2 
Summarizing table is called "avaluacio"

Can you help me? Thank you very much

```
For a = 1 To 7
For b = 2 To 2
For c = 1 To 7
For d = 2 To 6

Select Case sheet.ListObjects(alumne).DataBodyRange(a, b).Value

Case 1
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(avaluacio).DataBodyRange(c, d).Value = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(avaluacio).DataBodyRange(c, d).Value + 1
Case 2
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(avaluacio).DataBodyRange(c, d).Value = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(avaluacio).DataBodyRange(c, d).Value + 1

Case 3
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(avaluacio).DataBodyRange(c, d).Value = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(avaluacio).DataBodyRange(c, d).Value + 1

Case 4
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(avaluacio).DataBodyRange(c, d).Value = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(avaluacio).DataBodyRange(c, d).Value + 1

Case 5
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(avaluacio).DataBodyRange(c, d).Value = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(avaluacio).DataBodyRange(c, d).Value + 1

Case 6
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(avaluacio).DataBodyRange(c, d).Value = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(avaluacio).DataBodyRange(c, d).Value + 1

Case Else

End Select

Next
Next
Next
Next
```

Comment: What's the sense of a variable `b` going from 2 to 2? :-)

Comment: No sense, it's a silly mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It was simplier than I thought!!
I wasn't pointing the values the right cells and only one variable was necessary!

```
Dim a As Integer
For a = 1 To 7

Select Case sheet.ListObjects(alumne).DataBodyRange(a, 2).Value

Case 1
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(avaluacio).DataBodyRange(a, 2).Value = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(avaluacio).DataBodyRange(a, 2).Value + 1

Case 2
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(avaluacio).DataBodyRange(a, 3).Value = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(avaluacio).DataBodyRange(a, 3).Value + 1


Case 3
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(avaluacio).DataBodyRange(a, 4).Value = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(avaluacio).DataBodyRange(a, 4).Value + 1


Case 4
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(avaluacio).DataBodyRange(a, 5).Value = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(avaluacio).DataBodyRange(a, 5).Value + 1


Case 5
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(avaluacio).DataBodyRange(a, 6).Value = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(avaluacio).DataBodyRange(a, 6).Value + 1

Case Else

End Select
Next
```